# What is the hybridisation in BrF5

Tags: hybridization, halides

What  is the hybridisation of $\ce{BrF5}$ ? I find different sources giving different answers.

When I approach this problem , I don't find any exceptional case like $\ce{SH6}$ (in which hybridisation doesn't take place.) So it follows normal rules, but I find the opposite in many different books ?

I think it square pyramidal $\ce{sp^3d}$. I also face the same problem for other compounds like $\ce{H2S}$ and $\ce{PH3}$.

Comment: I am wondering is this kind of question morally justified? Since the d orbital contribution is already deputable in hypervalent molecule such as, SF6

Comment: What dou you mean by "Morally justified" ?

Comment: I mean, this question looks like an innocent homework assignment. But it is a complicated problem at the frontier of computational chemistry.

Comment: No , not a homework problem . I myself was practicing by writing some compounds , my intuition says the above one is square pyramidal . When I searched a library book a different story was written there .

Comment: There is, in-general, no one-to-one mapping between molecular geometry and hybridization.

Comment: Just a side quotation, http://depa.fquim.unam.mx/amyd/archivero/VBHIBRIDOSd_26401.pdf, "Figure 4. From a VB standpoint, the bonding in SF6 can be described using two, 2-electron bonds from sulfur sp hybrids pointing 180 away from each other and two, 2-electron bonds from sulfur p orbitals with
the remaining four electrons located on two fluorine atoms"

Comment: Thats a good source , but what about BrF5 ?

Comment: To be honest,  I never run an ab initio valence bond calculation as described in that reference. I suggest someone interested in this topic, run an ab initio valence bond calculation.

Comment: @InquisitiveMind $\ce{BrF5}$ should be composed of a standard 2e2c $\ce{Br-F}$ bond and two elongated 4e3c $\ce{F\bond{...}Br\bond{...}F}$ bonds (four-electron-three-centre bonds), giving it a square pyramidal structure with the central atom at the base of the pyramid. However, it probably fluctuates quickly between that and and the pentagonal bipyramid. In any case, remove d orbitals from your argumentation; they do not take part.

Comment: @Jan Hey my query on the hybridization of H2S and PH3

Answer (score 0):

Hybridisation of $\ce{BrF5}$ is $\ce{sp^3d^2}$ (involving one 4s, three 4p and two 4d orbitals) giving rise to octahedral geometry. But one hybrid orbital is occupied by lone pairs. So the effective shape of molecule is **square pyramidal**.